# Using command prompt on Windows to run an Application

Tags: shell, command-line, command, vlc

I have my VLC media player in Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC. Using the command prompt, if I cd into that folder, I can simply type "vlc" and the program will run.

But I'd like to be able to type "vlc" from any folder and have my VLC player run. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe`

or set your `PATH` enviroment variables with the vlc path appended